# Can I use my Raspberry Pi with 802.11 ah HaLow yet?

Tags: wifi

What I’m looking for is some type of USB adaptor or similar thing that I can use with a few Raspberry Pi’s to create a 802.11 ah network, but Googling hasn’t helped at all. Does anyone know how I might be able to get HaLow to work?

Comment: Are there even devices that support 802.11ah yet?  All Google shows are stories about the technology.  I'm not surprised Googling hasn't helped.

Comment: Maybe not such is available. 802.11ah as a chip is provided on http://newracom.com/products/ that was the only I found.

Answer (score 1):

This may be dated, but there are offerings now [2020] for balcony cards for the 3B+ & 4s from multiple vendors.

Here are a couple:

- https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/12/16/openwifi-is-an-open-source-linux-wifi-stack-running-on-fpga-hardware/
- https://www.silextechnology.com/unwired/industrys-first-802.11ah-halow-wireless-module-for-iot-devices
- https://www.mwee.com/news/halowtm-wi-fi-built-raspberry-pi-3
- http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/Silex%20Technology/Silex-SX-NEWAH-ProductBrief-Updated.pdf

There are more, but I am still evaluating them for a Project I oversee. I will return with more that I think are valid as I go through them.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a Raspberry Pi hat for 802.11ah on the market, made by Newracom with the NRC7292 chipset.

It is described on the [manufacturer's site](https://www.newracom.com/product/nrc7292-evk/). [Silex Technologies](https://www.silextechnology.com/connectivity-solutions/embedded-wireless/sx-newah-evaluation) also makes a different Pi hat using the same NRC7292 chip, but as part of their proprietary pre-certified module.